# Can I create queries in Arango DB using the Java interface?

Tags: java, arangodb

Although I can create and store queries using the Arango client, I can't find a way to create and retrieve them using the Arango java driver.  The only place I can see a QueryEntity returned is when asking for long running queries.

In the same way I create Collections and graphs programmatically using the java api, I also want to create a few queries for debugging. I can't find a way to do this using the java api.

Comment: Is the question not specific enough ? I assumed it was. I'm not sure what to change

Comment: Wish I could vote to reopen. Use this: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/blob/master/docs/Drivers/Java/Reference/README.md#executing-an-aql-statement `ArangoCursor<MyObject> cursor = db.query("for u in user return user", bindVars, null, MyObject.class);`

Comment: Perhaps change the title to "How do I create adhoc queries in arangodb using the java driver", and include the code you would like to be able to write. That gives a distinct answerable question so people don't have to think for a second to see what you are asking.